# Retrieve data from a Files Android

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a questionnaire project, but I need a question bank for it. I came up with the idea of writing them in a .txt file so that I can retrieve them later.

However, my current issue is that I am unable to retrieve the data from the file because Android cannot find its location. To retrieve the data, I am using the `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` methods.

Here's my code:

```java
try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("folder/filename.txt");
    BufferedReader lect = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String ligne = lect.readLine();

    while (ligne != null) {
        System.out.println(ligne);
        ligne = lect.readLine();
    }

    lect.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Best regards.

I am unable to retrieve the data from the file because Android cannot find its location.

Comment: You can't work with files that way in Android. You need to make it an asset or raw resource and get an input stream through the AssetManager or Resources. It's explained in the documentation on Android file management.

Comment: A better way to do this is to use a database, and with ROOM library its very easy to setup. You can store your data in tables and it will automatically be mapped to your classes. And since use only want to read the data, you can do it easily without much knowledge of SQL. Here is the resource https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: If Android cannot find its location then tell us at which location the file is ."folder/filename.txt" is no valid location.

Comment: The folders you can see when you connect a phone to your PC via USB are no real file-system. The used MTP protocol translates the paths so don't use them. First learn about internal storage and SD-card/shared storage. And if you want to look at the app private storage use Android Studio device explorer.